# Cross-platform mobile API -- Looking for recommendations

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, cordova, mobile-phones, jqtouch

So, yes, this is probably 1000th question on the subject.  However, my question is somewhat different from others that were asked about this, so please bear with me:

I am looking to develop a single mobile-app that targets the three/four popular and/or growing mobile platforms (Iphone, Android, WinPhone7, RIM).  This application is an extension of an existing SaaS system that my startup currently offers.  This mobile-app would provide a quick-and-simple way to view up-to-date status & chart & report information for the data that SaaS application collects.  Connection to the internet is required 100%.  No data entry besides username/password.  App is very simple with 5-6 "pages".

In phase 1, all that would need to be supported is for user to log in, get to see current status of his data stored in the cloud, get access to a few live reports

In phase 2, I'd like to be able to offer push-notification of certain key events from my servers in the cloud

My goals are:

1) The back-end processing that generates data for reports is already written in ASP.NET MVC2.  I want to re-use it.  It can be exposed as either a WCF service or published on a mobile-friendly website

2) I'd like to be able to deploy the patches faster than through the official app-stores/marketplaces.

3) I cannot afford to spend a lot of resources to target three-four proprietary platforms, for an app that is auxiliary to the vertical purpose of the business.  I want to develop it once for all 3-4 platforms.

4) I do not have access, nor do I want to purchase a Macbook

5) I do want to deploy thru the vendor-specific application marketplaces

6) I'd like to stay way from proprietary languages/frameworks/lock-ins

Sounds like what I need is a shell around a mobile-friendly site that can be packaged as an app.  Are there existing products that can make it REAL EASY for me to do so?  Will doing so, preclude me from doing push notifications in phase 2?
Can anyone recommend a "shell" product that would make a wrapper around the website as well as Javascript library that would look the best across all 4 platforms.  I've seen the names like Jqtouch, Jquery Mobile, etc... but not sure which ones are better for what I need.

Do I need PhoneGap?  I am not 100% sure here. Can PhoneGap use online-only html/javascript pages to translate into native code or must html/javascript files be distributed with the application?  I'd rather have the website itself drive the UI completely, as I can keep changing the website without various version approval processes from vendor market-stores.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you need Phonegap after reading about your project goals. You might consider a Web App instead of a native one if you 1) dont want to buy a mac (required for iOS even tho you can compile it in the cloud: https://build.phonegap.com/), and 2) want to apply and deploy updates anytime without going thru those platform independent marketplaces and approval processes.

jQuery Mobile would be an excellent choice, currently (at this very moment) in Alpha 3 but a very stable one and you can deploy your system on any of those platforms.  Note that if you focus your efforts in a Web App you can’t target the second phase you mentioned:  Push Notifications.

If you decide going Native, then Push Notifications services can be deployed into your Phonegap project once you setup the proper web services and certificates (take a look @ http://easyapns.com);

..and one quick note, the idea of phonegap is that all resources (html, js, images. etc) have to be distributed locally within the app and then getting online data (like reports, etc) using JSON from another web service, and that’s another easy task to accomplish. Phonegap DOES NOT compile your HTML files into native code (ObjectiveC or Java), it just load your Web App into a UIWebKit component at run time (in the case of an iOS app)

Another alternative could be using Titanium - http://www.appcelerator.com but this approach is more javascript oriented and your final app looks much more native. (not HTMLs here so I think thats a drawback for you)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I was also considering JQueryMObile or JQTouch... but i'd like to have a wrapper around the app so that it can be on app-stores and get the benefit of having free advertisement from them by searches... is this possible?  I would have been sure that some cheap-freebie kits already exist for this

Comment: As far as I know, Phonegap is the only way to do it, you just place your entire project into a "www" folder as you normally do in a web server (same folder structure) and Phonegap will do the rest :) - You just have to include a simple Javascript file in the header and off you go!